# Query is failing at pulling both words and integers in the same query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

While using Query, I kept receiving blanks in some columns while the data was correctly pulled in others.

I realized that the first column of data I was calling were numbers, the second were words, and the third were also numbers.

Columns 1 and 3 worked fine, but 2 kept on showing blanks. When I switched all to be words, then the queries worked out fine.

Here is a sheet demonstrating this problem. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JhD75CzDJxCiXdcD8pBXzThzzNWgCvv2M46UxA48Xzo/edit?usp=sharing

My goal is to be able to query the 9 values with

```
=query(A2:D4,"Select B,C,D where A contains 'id'")
```

What's going wrong? It must have to do with different types of data, right?

Answer (score 0):

`QUERY` is just a bit confused and auto-assumes the presence of header rows. to fix it just add 3rd `QUERY` parameter **`0`** - which defines there are no header rows:

```
=QUERY(A2:D4, "select B,C,D where A contains 'id'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That was easy! Thank you.